# Can't seem to start vehicle

Tags: chevrolet, cavalier

I have a 2000 Chevy Cavalier and I can't seem to get it started. I have replaced spark plugs, wires, core pack, and battery. Once I get it started and then I drive it back home it decides not to start again. Can someone please help me.

Comment: We'll need more info on the non start please: does the engine try to crank or do you hear silence, do the dash lights/radio/air turn on as normal, do you hear any grinding or other strange noises?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the car actually cranks over.

Before you throw more parts at your car you need to confirm spark and fuel.

Is the check engine light on?

Since you already replaced the ignition components you need to confirm spark when cranking. You can use an old spark plug and a lead wire to ground the electrode.

If you depress the schrader valve on the fuel rail test port does fuel come out? A fuel pressure gauge would be preferable but sometimes just making sure fuel is getting to the rail is enough.

How about injector signal? If you have one a noid light would be preferable, but you can also backprobe the injector signal wire and check for ground.